# How do I prevent a footnote bar from a graphics page with no footnote?

Tags: graphics, footnotes

I have a page with a graphic that fills the entire page.  The previous page has a footnote.  The horizontal line that separates the footnote from the text appears on both pages (the one with the text and footnote and the page with the graphic).  How can I prevent the footnote bar from appearing on the graphic page?

Comment: [Welcome to TeX.SX!](//meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/1436) Please help us help you and add a [minimal working example (MWE)](//meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/228) that illustrates your problem. Reproducing the problem and finding out what the issue is will be much easier when we see compilable code, starting with `\documentclass{...}` and ending with `\end{document}`.